# gclient runhooks throwing error when trying to build Chromium for Android on Windows

Tags: android, chromium

I've tried to build chromium android app on Windows. I've run `gclient sync` then I tried to run `gclient runhooks`.

I'm getting this error message

```
Running hooks:  52% (51/97) Fetch Android AFDO profile
________ running 'vpython.bat src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py --newest_state=src/chrome/android/profiles/newest.txt --local_state=src/chrome/android/profiles/local.txt --output_name=src/chrome/android/profiles/afdo.prof --gs_url_base=chromeos-prebuilt/afdo-job/llvm' in 'D:\chromium'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py", line 125, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py", line 121, in main
    RetrieveProfile(up_to_date_profile, new_tmpfile, args.gs_url_base)
  File "src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py", line 77, in RetrieveProfile
    CheckCallOrExit(['bzip2', '-d', out_path])
  File "src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py", line 37, in CheckCallOrExit
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "D:\Android\depot_tools\bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin\python\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Android\depot_tools\bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin\python\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Error: Command 'vpython.bat src/tools/download_optimization_profile.py --newest_state=src/chrome/android/profiles/newest.txt --local_state=src/chrome/android/profiles/local.txt --output_name=src/chrome/android/profiles/afdo.prof --gs_url_base=chromeos-prebuilt/afdo-job/llvm' returned non-zero exit status 1 in D:\chromium
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build Chromium for Android using Windows. You need to do it from Linux, Ubuntu is supported. Windows host for building Android for Chromium is not supported.

Comment: Is there is any possibility to build chromium for Android using windows?

Comment: Nope, I have posted it as an answer too so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You can view supported distros to build Chromium in src/build/install-build-deps.sh, as for now it can run on the following distros:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty with EoL April 2022)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial with EoL April 2024)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic with EoL April 2028)
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal with Eol April 2030)
- Ubuntu 19.04 (disco)
- Ubuntu 19.10 (eoan)
- Debian 8 (jessie) or later

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build Chromium for Android using Windows, **which is not supported at all**. Even macOS is not supported for building Chromium for Android. You should try to build it from Linux, more specifically Ubuntu to build it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rarer case.

You can try by installing the `file` command:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install file
```

For reference, this is the error I got:

```
➜  src git:(0afea4328b) ./build/install-build-deps.sh
Running as non-root user.
You might have to enter your password one or more times for 'sudo'.

Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                   
Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy InRelease   
Fetched 229 kB in 1s (403 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Finding missing packages...
Building apt package list.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 940, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 933, in main
    install_packages(options)
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 845, in install_packages
    packages = find_missing_packages(options)
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 819, in find_missing_packages
    packages = package_list(options)
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 758, in package_list
    packages = (dev_list() + lib_list() + dbg_list(options) +
  File "/home/mhd/Desktop/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.py", line 314, in dev_list
    if "ELF 64-bit" in subprocess.check_output(["file", "-L",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'
```